# React Conditional Update of a List

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I am trying to understand how to change the elements of a list. Below is a simple example of what I am trying to do.

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
/* 
if(numbers[1] == 2)
   numbers[1] = 5;
else 
   numbers[1] = 0;
*/
const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
  <li>{number}</li>
);
```

I need to update an element of a list based on the comments above. But I am running into a lot of errors. Is this the wrong way to work with lists in React. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you should add a key into the `li`: `(number, index) => <li key={index}>{number}</li>`

Answer (score 1):

[Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback receives the current index as the 2nd param, so you can use a nested ternary in JSX, and modify the rendered item if the index is 1:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const listItems = numbers.map((number, index) =>
  <li>{index === 1 ? (number === 2 ? 5 : 0) : number}</li>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand your `listItems` is NOT a component, it's just an array of react elements. So you need to put them inside the render method of some component.

```
class ListItemComp extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
      <li>{number}</li>
    );

    return (<ul>{listItems}</ul>);
  }
}
```

Second, if you want to make change to the data, and you want react to know that change and re-render the view, then you need to call `this.setState()` somewhere, and make sure the data changed is accessible from `this.state`. So let's change the component a bit.

```
class ListItemComp extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()

    const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    this.state = {
      numbers: numbers
    };

    // first it'll render "1,2,3,4,5"
    // wait 3 seconds, it re-render to "1,5,3,4,5"
    setTimeout(() => { 
      if (numbers[1] == 2)
        numbers[1] = 5;
      else 
        numbers[1] = 0;

      this.setState({ numbers: numbers });
    }, 3000);
  }

  render () {
    const listItems = this.state.numbers.map((number) =>
      <li>{number}</li>
    );

    return (<ul>{listItems}</ul>);
  }
}
```